# How to display the truncated information in SCIP?

Tags: optimization, scip

[image: Output]

I noticed that between 447s and 181 mins, the SCIP shell does not display the output. Is there a command or a way to display the iterations between 447s and 181 mins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parameter `display/freq` to a lower value, e.g. 1, to print a line for every new node instead of only every 100th node. You may also want to increase `display/verblevel` to get more output.